# Values from vector differ from the original value

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I am confused with C++ `vector` and ask for help.
I declare a class `CBoundaryPoint`:

```
class CBoundaryPoint:
{
public:
    double m_param;
    int m_index;    
}
```

And then I define a `vector`:

```
vector<CBoundaryPoint> vBoundPoints;
CBoundaryPoint bp;
double param;
// other codes
bp.m_param = param;
vBoundPoints.push_back( bp );
```

It surprises me that for every element in `vBoundPoints`, the value of `m_param` is totally different from the given value param. I just don't know why.

For Example:

```
param = 0.3356;
bp.m_param = param; // so bp.param equals to 0.3356;
vBoundPoints.push_back( bp ); // while (*(vBoundPoints.end()-1)).m_param = -6.22774385622041925e+066;  same case to other elements
```

So what happened and why? I'm using VS2010.

Comment: Could you add some code to show how you are checking the values?

Comment: Yeah, you want to probably use .rbegin () or better yet .back () instead of .end () - 1

Comment: Please give a short, complete code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your code should work, the reason it doesn't is that you've made a mistake somewhere in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: The cool thing is that if I do .resize() the vector to exactly number of elements in the vector, then end()-1 gives the proper value.. but if I .resize() the vector to something larger, then it gives me a garbage value :D as expected. I've learned something today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably get garbage when you resize the vector or create a vector of a certain size using the `size_type` constructor. You get default-constructed objects in your vector, and these contain primmitive types. Since you have no user defined default constructor, the values are essentially random, or "garbage".

You can fix this by adding a default constructor to your class:

```
class CBoundaryPoint:
{
public:
    CBoundaryPoint : m_param(), m_index() {} // initializes members to 0. and 0
    double m_param;
    int m_index;    
}
```